# CKEditor : How to prevent bookmarks to be wrapped in paragraphs?

Tags: ckeditor, bookmarks, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to use CKEditor for a project and I found the need for bookmarks. [The documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_range.html#createBookmark) says that the intrusive way to create bookmarks add `span` elements in the source. This is just fine with me and that is exactly what I would want it to do.
However, I can see in the source that the `span` elements are wrapped in `p` elements.

```
<p><span id="cke_bm_147S" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</p>
```

This creates problems for me with the way the text is displayed and mainly when trying to navigate the document.
I didn't find anything that even mentions the creation of these `p` elements. Could I have set something wrong? Is there a way to prevent these to be created?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `span` bookmark is an inline element so it cannot be the root element of the content. It is wrapped in a block element (which is by default a paragraph).

This behaviour depends on editor [`enterMode`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-enterMode). If it is a default one - [`ENTER_P`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-ENTER_P) - you will have a `p` element as a wrapper. For [`ENTER_DIV`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-ENTER_DIV) you will have a `div` element. And for [`ENTER_BR`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-ENTER_BR) there will be no wrapper which means it is the effect you would like to achieve.

Check this [codepen for demo](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/bLoxxv?editors=1011).

**Please keep in mind** that `enterMode` other that `ENTER_P` is not recommended [due to some caveats](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_enterkey.html). So maybe in your case it will be better to reconsider some different solutions instead of changing `enterMode`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering the question. However, as you suspected, it was not really a solution for me. Honestly I'm not sure to understand what you meant with "the span bookmark is an inline element so it cannot be the root element of the content". The extract I provided is just part of a document and not the entire document. There is content before and after.

Comment: It is explained in a second paragraph I wrote - usually (unless you use `ENTER_BR` mode) inline element needs to be wrapped in block element. Inline elements cannot be top level elements in the editor. That's why there is `p` element you mentioned. What is the reason that this approach doesn't fit your case?

Comment: Hello and thanks for still following this. I guess I don't really understand what exactly is an inline element and what it means for it to be the root element. Should I wrap the entire content in a p to prevent more to be added? It doesn't work for me because I want these bookmarks to be invisible reference points, accessible only programmatically. Having the p added automagically whenever, not only changes the way the document looks but also makes it hard to predict how to navigate from bookmark to bookmark.